# Как 'связать' 2 элемента на странице?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Есть 2 `input[type=range]` (вообще их 4, но это не так важно). Нужно чтобы изменяя 1 ползунок, изменялся и другой. Уже 2 сижу и никак. За все отвечает модель, можно ли как-то передавать состояние постоянно между 2-мя элементами?
Все написано на `backbone`

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример набросал: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vyoJZY

```js
// создаём общий класс модели
var RangeControlModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults : {
    value : 15
  }
});

// создаём экземпляр класса модели с данными:
var rangeControlModel = new RangeControlModel();

var RangeControl = Backbone.View.extend({

  events : {
    // 'change' или 'input':
    'change' : 'update'
  },
  
  initialize : function () {
    // связываем представления с созданной моделью данных, где у нас хранится общее значение для range input'а
    this.model = rangeControlModel;
    // слушаем изменения модели и вызываем рендер, если они произошли
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:value', this.render);
    this.render();
  },
  
  update : function (evnt) {
    this.model.set('value', this.el.value);
  },
  
  render : function () {
    // ... 
    this.$el.val(this.model.get('value'));
  }
  
});

var range1 = new RangeControl({
  el : '.range1'
});

var range2 = new RangeControl({
  el : '.range2'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
els = $('#ranges input[type="range"]');
els.bind('change', function(){
  els.val(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ranges">
  <input type="range">
  <input type="range">
  <input type="range">
  <input type="range">
</div>
```

Comment: это антисовет какой-то. в вопросе правильная концепция заложена - автор хочет создать backbone представления, зависящие от данных, а не код на jquery